# Install GCC on an old version of Fedora

Tags: fedora, software-installation

```
 yum install gcc-4.9.2
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: fedora. Please verify its path and try again
[root@localhost IFC946x_Mfgtest_880138_Ver1.2]# 
this is the error i am facing while installing gcc.
```

How to install gcc for fedora 14 ?

Comment: Backporting gcc 4.9 is probably an option, but you are better off upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 14 is ancient release. It is not supported for long time. Please get current version of Fedora, it is Fedora 21. Then your problems should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that you may want to consider upgrading to a newer release, I grant that this is not always an option.

You can compile from source (assuming you have a working older version of gcc), which may be found from the GNU project [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/).